# Permission denied, please try again

Tags: raspbian

hi I have installed the raspbian os on an sd card and want to connect it to mu ubuntu 18.04 screen but its keep saying that : 
"Permission denied" , so I logged in via a screen and changed the password but still the same result ... what should I do?
* I also chek the IP of my pi and make sure that it's right.

Comment: `connect it to mu ubuntu 18.04 screen` - how are you trying to do this

Comment: What is the difference between the `mu ubuntu 18.04 screen` and the screen you use to log in to change the password?

Comment: im trying to do that by ether net cable ,,, i connect it to my tv screen